# Can the game be won by the intergalactic council vote in multiplayer?

Tags: master-of-orion-2

We've been playing (along with two AI players) for a while now, and the universe gets crowded. Does multiplayer provide the council vote winning option or do we *have* to eradicate one another (or the Antarans)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I found no actual sources for this, after several hours of being allied with both my human opponent and the only remaining AI player without any voting, I suspect the answer is "No".

Comment: I own this game and play it all the time. Yes the game can be won by Intergalactic Council Vote in Multiplayer. There are conditions that must be met for the council to convene, and further conditions that PREVENT the council from convening either temporarily or permanently. Ill gather all the neccesary stasitical info and post an answer in a day or so.

Comment: @Ender Great to hear, can't wait for your answer :-)

Comment: wait, your playing with JUST AI or with human opponents as well? If your playing with humans then my information is lacking as I've never had the oppourtunity. (And I'd like to know how your doing it if a hotseat isnt involved)

Comment: @Ender One human, myself and two AIs. Well, now only one, the other was too demanding and spying... I have re-bought MOO2 from [gog.com](http://www.gog.com/gamecard/master_of_orion_1_2) for that reason (plus I wanted the English version), their setup uses dosbox plus `ipxnet` so we can play via LAN. I don't know if you need to use a VPN for internet multiplayer though.